# Can't get left position with global stylesheet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stylesheet, position

I need to get the upper left position of an image in JavaScript. I define the location of an image in a global style sheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
img.movable { position:relative; top:0px; left:375px; }
</style>
```

When I define the image using the global style

```
<img id="image11" class="movable" src="testimage.jpg" onclick="jump()" />
```

The `style.left` attribute is empty:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jump() {
    xpos = document.getElementById("image11").style.left;
    alert( "style.left="+xpos );

    xpos = document.getElementById("image11").offsetLeft;
    alert( "offsetLeft="+xpos );
}
</script>
```

But when I define the image using an inline style:

```
<img id="image11" style="position:relative; top:0px; left:375px;" src="logo.jpg" onclick="jump()" />
```

`style.left` contains a value.

This behaviour is the same for IE8 and Firefox. Any ideas why that is?

Cheers,

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`el.style` is actually a map of all the css properties applied using the `style` attribute. To get styles defined in stylesheets or default browser styles, you need to use computed style. [Quirksmode, as usual, is a first stop](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).

Comment: +1 for the link. The function getStyle(el,styleProp) solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The DOM element that represents the IMG tag you specified has its own style property, and its values will override any given by globals.  Unfortunately in this case, the property of the element you specified will indeed be empty, as the values do not cascade down to the JavaScript object level.

You will need to get the position from either the offsetLeft property or the CSS rule itself.

Answer (score 0):

.style properties only relate to inline css. Styles specified in a stylesheet will thus not be present in the .style list. If you want to get the position of an element on the page (as opposed to viewport) something like this should work:

```
function getNodePosition(node) {
  var top = left = 0;
  while (node) {        
    if (node.tagName) {
        top = top + node.offsetTop;
        left = left + node.offsetLeft;      
        node = node.offsetParent;
    } else {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
  } 
  return [top, left];
}
```

Adapted from Quirksmode. OffsetTop and OffsetLeft are wrt to the parent, so this iterates up the tree to get the total offsets, and hence page position. If you want to know the position wrt the viewport, you can adjust the values returned here by the scroll distance.

Answer (score 0):

Get Left Element of a given HTMLElement

```
function getHTMLElementLeft(HTMLElement, left)
{
    if (left == undefined)
    {
        var left = 0;
    }
    if (HTMLElement.nodeType == 1)
    {
        left += HTMLElement.offsetLeft;
        if (HTMLElement.offsetParent)
        {
            left = getHTMLElementLeft(HTMLElement.offsetParent, left);
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```